# How to append struts 2 UI tag(example <s:textfield tag) using Jquery append() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I want to add row dynamically in a table,In that table one autocomplete field is present in each row.So, I have to use Struts 2 UI tag i.e `<s:textfield`.But i use this tag in jquery append() funcution ,i am getting error.The smaple code and the error are given below,

**Jquery code:**

```
 $("#InvoiceDetails").append('<tr><td><s:textfield cssClass="\form-control\" onclick="\autocompleteWithHiddenId(this,\'autocomplteWithHidenId.action?tblname=ops_Client&colname=Client_Name&colnameId=Client_Id\',\'clientId\',\'\');\" onfocus="\autocompleteWithHiddenId(this,\'autocomplteWithHidenId.action?tblname=ops_Client&colname=Client_Name&colnameId=Client_Id\',\'clientId\',\'\');\" \ onchange=\"getIndentList(this);\" /><s:textfield cssClass=\"form-control hide\" type=\"hidden\" id=\"clientId\" name=\"invoiceTo.clientId\" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /invoice.jsp(146,86) Unterminated <s:textfield tag
```

Comment: Even if you could append, it wont work; those are server side tags and should being processed at server side

Comment: @YasserZamani so how can i do that?Is there any other solution.

Comment: I found http://javaonlineguide.net/2014/10/struts-2-adding-removing-dynamic-rows-and-getting-values-in-struts-2-action.html via search

Comment: @YasserZamani Yupp it is doing at server end.But how can I do this using jquery?

Comment: Use plain HTML tags or return JSON or return JSP with S2 tags.

Comment: @SubrataGhosh It's not good to mess a code with struts tags, just use plain html on the client and struts json services.